# Iphone - NSUserDefault settings do not appear on the settings page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am an iOS development newbie. I am implementing some sample code, but try as I might I do not see my NSUserDefault settings on the settings page. What needs to be done for that? Also, where do you specify the UI for the settings page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your settings bundle, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html